# Error in installing python selenium bindings on fedora

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to install python-selenium bindings by seeing [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PythonBindings)

When i am trying to import the following command, it is showing an error below

```
from selenium.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver
```

Result:

```
from selenium.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named firefox.webdriver
```

I searched a lot to solve this, but i didn't get the right example to do this, can anyone please provide me a way and an example on how to install python selenium bindings and why the above error is returned.

Thanks in advance..........

**Edited :**
I editing my code according to below answer,and tried the following , i got the below

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.Firefox()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.21.3-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 51, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.21.3-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.21.3-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 44, in launch_browser
    self._wait_until_connectable()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.21.3-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 81, in _wait_until_connectable
    self._get_firefox_output())
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. The output was: *** LOG addons.xpi: startup\n*** LOG addons.xpi: checkForChanges\n*** LOG addons.xpi: Opening database\n*** LOG addons.xpi: No changes found\nFailed to dlopen /usr/lib/libX11.so.6\ndlerror says: /usr/lib/libX11.so.6: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32\n'
```

And also saying that there is `some crash in firefox 1.0....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated on that page they have re-organized the package. Use the second code listing I have posted here.

> One advantage of using trunk as of writing, is the reorganization of the package. Previously, to initialize a browser you had to perform,

```
from selenium.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver
driver = WebDriver()
```

> This has been changed, so now all that is required is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

EDIT (for new error):

Are you running this from a linux server with no X display? Firefox requires a display to render itself. Take a look at [PyVirtualDisplay](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyVirtualDisplay) for running "headless" (without X).

Comment: I edited the code as above and i got the arror which i had stated above.

Comment: Check the EDIT on my Post. If you're running a server with not X Display you're going to have to run it headless with a tool like PyVirtualDisplay.

Comment: I had installed PyVirtualDisplay and i am extremely sorry that i don't know how to run with X display , i had done same as it is shown in that page and still getting the same error. Can u please provide me an example code of how to remove this error.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem on a Fedora 17 64bits.
selenium - problem with loading x_ignore_nofocus.so
PROBLEM

Selenium fails to start Firefox with following error:

'The browser appears to have exited before we could connect.
The output was: Failed to dlopen /usr/lib/libX11.so.6\ndlerror
says: /usr/lib/libX11.so.6: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32\n'

It is because x_ignore_nofocus library tries to load 32bit version of the libX11 instead of 64bit. In my system there are following versions of libX11:

```
find / | grep libX11.so.6 | xargs file
```

/usr/lib64/libX11.so.6: symbolic link to libX11.so.6.3.0
/usr/lib64/libX11.so.6.3.0: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped
/usr/lib/libX11.so.6:       symbolic link to `libX11.so.6.3.0'
/usr/lib/libX11.so.6.3.0:   ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped

SOLUTION
Change symbolic link /usr/lib/libX11.so.6 to point to the 64-bit version /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6.3.0:

```
mv /usr/lib/libX11.so.6 /usr/lib/libX11.so.6.bak
ln -s /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6.3.0 /usr/lib/libX11.so.6
```

After that selenium started to work.
[Source](http://sebgoo.blogspot.com/2012/02/selenium-problem-with-loading-x-ignore.html?showComment=1342840505275#c7321743917714208108)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, we would like you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the [link for reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot.